# Magento 2: how to get the grand total of the minicart and cart on custom header template in when we add new products in the cart

Tags: magento2, ajax, mini-cart, magento2minicart

how to get the grand total of the minicart and cart on custom header template when we add or update the new products in the cart in magento 2 witout refreshing the page.

We can get via ajax of minicart.js function. Can you please suggest how I can do with the same?

Thanks in advance!!